# Using an "If statement" to get the value of the coloured text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to make a thing where when you click a button, the text will turn green, and if you click it again, the text will turn blue. My strategy in doing this was to test if the text was green or if it was blue, but I didn't know how:

```
var topcon = document.getElementsByClassName("topchoice");

function show() {
    if(topcon.style.color = "blue") {
        for (count=0; count < topcon.length; count++) {
        topcon[count].style.color = "green";
        }
    }
    else if(topcon.style.color = "green") {
        for (count=0; count < topcon.length; count++) {
            topcon[count].style.color = "blue";
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. It will just stay the same colour when I call the `show()` function. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

And if you're wondering why I used a loop, that is because you can't `getElementsByClassName` without an array, because elements work with arrays.

Comment: you are assigning it with `=` you want `===`

Comment: `topcon` is an node collection, it does not have the style property, so you should be getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`

Comment: What are you trying to do? are you trying to change the color of all element based on color of the first one, or each elements color has to be toggle independently

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zbgcvgnz/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues in the code

- Need to use comparison operator `==` or `===` for comparison
- `topcon` is a node list, so it does not have the `style` property. This will cause your code to throw an error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`

```js
var topcon = document.getElementsByClassName("topchoice");

function show() {
  var el;
  for (count = 0; count < topcon.length; count++) {
    el = topcon[count];
    if (el.style.color == "blue") {
      el.style.color = "green";
    } else if (el.style.color == "green") {
      el.style.color = "blue";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topchoice" style="color: green">1</div>
<div class="topchoice" style="color: green">1</div>
<div class="topchoice" style="color: green">1</div>
<div class="topchoice" style="color: green">1</div>

<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this helps!

Comment: But, there's only one problem: When I try to style the text in the CSS file, it doesn't change when I try to click the button. By any chance, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @MCGuy Can you share more details

Comment: Basically, when I do `style="color:green"` it works, but when it do it in a CSS file like this: `#topchoice { color: green }` the colour won't change when I call the `show()` function

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zbgcvgnz/2/ - supported in IE10+ - can look for pollyfills for older versions

Answer (score 1):

Need to use comparison operator of "===" rather than assignment operator of "=". It's also a bit confusing since it looks like you're expecting topcon to be an array of items, in which case you need to also change your comparison to an element in what was selected.

```
var topcon = document.getElementsByClassName("topchoice");

function show() {
  var changeColor = "blue";
  if(topcon && topcon.length) {
    if(topcon[0].style.color === "blue") {
      changeColor = "green";
    } else {
      changeColor = "blue";
    }
    for (count=0; count < topcon.length; count++) {
       topcon[count].style.color = changeColor;
    }
  }
};
```